# Hospedando site no Windows Azure de graca?

Tags: microsoft-azure

O Windows Azure permite um tempo de trial de 30 dias para testar a plataforma, mas e depois disso? Existe uma opcao gratis de hospedagem de aplicacoes .net, mas nao esta claro se voce tera algum custo ou apos o periodo de trial se sera possivel continuar a utilizar os planos mais basicos gratuitamente.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Comforme [Perguntas frequentes sobre compra do Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/pt-br/pricing/faq/):

> *Sim. Com nosso novo recurso Limite de Gastos, os clientes que assinarem a oferta Avaliação Gratuita por 90 Dias, MSDN ou Cloud Essentials poderão utilizar o Windows Azure sem nenhum receio de serem cobrados, desde que mantenham o recurso Limite de Gastos ativado.*

E em [Limite de Gastos do Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/pt-br/pricing/spending-limits/), há duas partes que chamam atenção:

1. *Agora, por padrão, todos os novos clientes que se inscreverem para a oferta de avaliação ou uma de nossas ofertas para membros (por exemplo, a oferta do MSDN) terão um Limite de Gastos de $0.* **Boa notícia**
2. *Quando seu uso ultrapassar as quantias mensais incluídas na sua oferta, seu serviço será desabilitado no restante daquele mês de cobrança (...)*. **Existe um limite, se passar dele, seu serviço será desativado**.
3. *Se a assinatura tiver sido desabilitada porque o Limite de Gastos foi atingido, clique na notificação: "A assinatura alcançou o Limite de Gastos e foi desabilitada para evitar encargos". Caso contrário, clique em "Remover limite de gastos" na área Tarefas.* Ou seja, para ter sua aplicação ativa, você teria que reativar pagamento, e uma vez ativado pagamento, você nunca mais poderá desativar essa feature.

A única coisa que não está clara é se o limite básico sempre estará disponível de graça e você só paga a diferença, como ocorre com o free tier da Amazon EC2 pelo período de um ano.

**Então, sim, é possível usar de graça. Porém sua aplicação não poderá exceder os limites impostos por eles**.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas informacoes Emerson!

Answer (score 3):

A oferta gratuita tem um tempo de duração de 30 dias com 200 dólares  de crédito e o prazo de validade é para o que for atingido primeiro. Após isso você irá atualizar a sua conta para o modelo tradicional de contratação chamado Pay-As-You-GO (pago pelo uso).

Quanto à questão de se poder utilizar um web site gratuito a resposta é sim, mesmo tendo uma conta PAYG, cada subscription tem como limite 10 Web Sites gratuitos, 1 base de dados MySQL e outra de SQL Database com o tamanho de 20MB e válido pelos primeiros 12 meses de uso.

> Note:
>   Relational Database: one 20MB Azure SQL Database and one 20MB MySQL database are available at the subscription level for the first twelve months of use; standard rates apply thereafter.

Referência com tabela demonstrativa dos limites de Web Site gratuito e locall onde contém a nota acima: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/web-sites/

Somente será gerado algum tipo de custo caso você utilize algum outro recurso, fora isso nada será cobrado.

Boa sorte e sucesso!