# Projeto Asp.Net MVC em Medium-Trust

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web.config

Tenho um projeto em Asp.Net MVC usando .NET Framework 4.5, mas meu host é compartilhado e tem uma política de segurança que só permite Medium-Trust (salve Locaweb).

Ao publicar a aplicação, mesmo alterando o Web.config para Medium-Trust a aplicação não funciona. Acredito que seja alguma DLL que solicita algum serviço que não é possível ser acessado em Medium-Trust.

Por precaução alterei todas as DLLs da referencia para `Copy Local = true`, mas ainda assim não tem funcionado.

Existe alguma forma de fazer funcionar da maneira como está?

Comment: eu passei exatamente por esse problema na Locaweb e não teve jeito. Precisei fazer um downgrade para o MVC 4, com Framework 4.0 e substituir o Ninject pelo Autofac.

Comment: Opa @LeandroAngelo pode transformar seu comentário em uma resposta dando um pouco mais de detalhes por favor? Eu gostaria de entender um pouco melhor essa alternativa...

Comment: Você ainda precisa da mesma coisa? Um serviço gratis? É essa sua pergunta?

Comment: @durtto minha pergunta é se existe alguma alternativa para fazer o projeto Asp.Net MVC funcionar em um servidor Medium-Trust, mesmo que tenha que usar MVC 4 ou outra coisa do tipo como comentou o [LeandroAngelo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97315/projeto-asp-net-mvc-em-medium-trust?noredirect=1#comment212886_97315)

Answer (score 2):

Vou traduzir essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849801/is-trying-to-develop-for-medium-trust-a-lost-cause/17218344#17218344).

A posição oficial da equipe ASP.NET é que a confiança média é obsoleto. Isto significa que algumas coisas:

- Estamos resolvendo automaticamente todos os bugs relacionados-Trust
  Médio relatados a nós como "não vai resolver".
- Nós fornecemos orientações para hosters que eles devem migrar de
  confiança média e uso adequado isolamento de nível OS vez
  (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2698981).
- Estamos removendo o suporte a confiança média dos quadros que
  desenvolvemos (MVC, WebAPI, SignalR, e assim por diante). Daqui para
  frente, as aplicações construídas nestas estruturas exigirá confiança
  total.

Aqui, o termo "confiança média" acima para refere-se a todas as configurações de confiança não-completos em ASP.NET, incluindo o uso dos níveis de confiança embutidos (Minimal, Baixa, Média, Alta) ou quaisquer níveis de confiança personalizados.

Edite 26 de maio de 2015: O .NET Framework como um todo tem preterido confiança parcial, e os clientes são aconselhados a não confiar nele como um limite de segurança. De MSDN:

Você também tem opção de usar o azure, consegue hospedar inclusive de forma gratuita um site básico com um banco de até 20Mb. (comentário do usuário [Renatto Machado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17637/como-resolver-o-problema-de-medium-trust-em-asp-net))

Comment: Falando em Windows Azure, como conseguir hospedar de forma gratuita e permanente? já que no site informa que só dá para fazer avaliacao gratuita por 30 das.

Comment: Não é possível utilizar dessa forma que relata. Microsoft oferece serviços e produtos que devem ser pagos. Não tem como escapar não.

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse serviço https://appharbor.com/pricing, tem muita gente falando bem dele. me parece que tem um plano free. Qual o propósito de sua aplicação? Estudo ou comercial?

Comment: Olha o que eu achei: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6222/hospedando-site-no-windows-azure-de-graca

Comment: Quero botar meu site no Windows Azure para uso pessoal apenas.

Comment: Eu tb tinha visto esse Link, mas não quis interferir pois pode dar errado e gerar cobrança para você